# Quando cria um novo par num dicionário perde os dados anteriores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário

Estou criando um *dict* do zero, porém quando eu adiciono algum par novo, os pares antigos se perdem. Se tento imprimir 'nome' por exemplo, dá erro.

```
cidade = {
    'nome': 'São Paulo',
    'estado': 'São Paulo'
}

print(cidade)    
print(cidade['nome'])    
cidade = {'país': 'Brasil'}    
#print(cidade['nome'])    
print(cidade)
```

Tirem o comentário do penúltimo `print()` que vocês verão o erro acontecendo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não está criando um novo par de chave e valor, você está criando um novo dicionário e guardando na mesma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), por isso o valor anterior dela é perdido, já que não pode guardar dois valores diferentes na mesma variável.

Se deseja adicionar um elemento novo deve criar isso através da sintaxe padrão do dicionário dizendo que tem uma chave que antes não existia e guardando um valor na chave e não no dicionário. A chave é como se fosse um variável diferente, ou seja, o dicionário é um objeto cheio de variáveis.

Outra forma é usar um método que o objeto de dicionário tem por padrão e ele muda o objeto para você. [Documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20update#dict.update).

```
cidade = {
    'nome': 'São Paulo',
    'estado': 'São Paulo'
}
cidade['país'] = 'Brasil'
cidade.update({'cep': '01000'})
print(cidade)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/870nk6). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/nbzjjyuzth-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Collection/UpdateDict.py).